# How do i find out the version of outlook using javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin

I am building an app which requires integration with MS Outlook. For that i need to find out the version of Outlook installed in my system. Now i need to use a JavaScript function to find out the current version Outlook installed. Can someone help me out

Comment: Plain javascript won't help... Where/How is executed that javascript? You won't have access to information of that type from a webpage, I assume you are trying to create a plugin or something? Tell us more!

Comment: yes i'm using a outlook add-in. where we use office APIs for getting details from outlook

Answer (score 0):

YOu cannot find the exact outlook version. Nor should your require that. The Add in can be set to work for only a minimum API version, and you could also simply test on feature availability just like we do in browsers nowadays.

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets?product=outlook

Comment: Can we set the default message body in RTF format instead of Text or HTML. Currently it is setting as HTML or TEXT format

Comment: Could be, but you should very good reasons to do so... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-message-format-to-HTML-Rich-Text-Format-or-plain-text-338a389d-11da-47fe-b693-cf41f792fefa

Answer (score 0):

This code I am using for get selected format from outlook but when we select `RTF` format in outlook this function give us `HTML` as a selected format instead of `RTF`. But is there any option how we can get a selected format as `RTF` when it selected in ***outlook***

`Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getTypeAsync(function (result) {
   ...
}`

Comment: @Salketer Any help regarding this..??

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a COM-Add-In, you can use the [`Office.Diagnostics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.diagnostics) interface and/or the [`Office.ContextInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.contextinformation?view=common-js-preview) interface. Both provide data about the Outlook version and the platform it is running on.

**`Office.Diagnostics`**

In Outlook, this interface is available at `Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics`

- [`hostName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.diagnostics?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-diagnostics-hostname-member): Gets a string that represents the type of Outlook client.
- [`hostVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.diagnostics?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-diagnostics-hostversion-member): Gets a string that represents the version of either the Outlook client or the Exchange Server (for Outlook Web)
- [`OWAView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.diagnostics?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-diagnostics-owaview-member): Gets a string that represents the current view of Outlook on the web.

**`Office.ContextInformation`**

- [`host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.contextinformation?view=common-js-preview#office-office-contextinformation-host-member): Gets the Office application in which the add-in is running.
- [`platform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.contextinformation?view=common-js-preview#office-office-contextinformation-platform-member): Gets the platform on which the add-in is running.
- [`version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.contextinformation?view=common-js-preview#office-office-contextinformation-version-member): Gets the version of Office on which the add-in is running.

You can then refer to the update history to match the version number you get to the Outlook application.

Windows: [Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date), [Office 2016 and 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2019), [Office 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2013)

Mac: [Office 365 and 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-for-mac), [Office 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/release-notes-office-2016-mac)

Outlook Web (exchange on-premise): [Exchange Server 2013, 2016, 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/new-features/build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=exchserver-2019)